# Value optimized out in GDB: Can gdb handle decoding it automatically?

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-construction, gdb, compiler-optimization

1) First I want to know, how to decode such variables ?

I know the solutions to this problem, remove optimization flag, make it volatile, I dont want to do all that. Is there any solution which can be done without compiling the source again ? The problem is whenever i make any changes, it takes ages to compile, so I dont want to compile it with different optimization flags, also I had tried once changing the optimization flag, but it crashed just because of change in compilation flags, for reasons I cant fathom.

Also I am not able to find documentation about understanding various registers when I do "info reg". i was expecting some variable ( whose value I knew, what would it be ) but info reg is showing me all different values. I am missing something here. The architecture I am working on is x86_64

2) I want to know what are the restrictions faced by gdb to decode such register variables ? Or is this problem already tackled by someone. I have read at many places that going through the assembly code, you can find out which variable is in that register. If thats true, why it cant be build into gdb. Please point me to relevant pages if there are solutions to this problem

Comment: The only things close a question here are "I want to know what are the restrictions" & "Please point me to relevant pages".   You haven't described a problem, and these are very vague and open ended questions that don't actually solve a problem.  Others may disagree, but I'm voting to close.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. My basic problem is how do I find out the values of such a variable which is optimized out. I know the solutions to this problem, remove optimization flag, make it volatile, I dont want to do all that. Is there any solutions which can be done without compiling the source again ? you can assume that the library is 3rd party code to which I dont have access. What else should I describe. Then definitely there are some problems faced by gdb because of which it cant display such variables. That is what I call "restrictions".

Comment: Your comment is MILES away from your original post.  In your comment, you ask "how do I find out the values of such a variable which is optimized out?".  (that is a real question, unlike your original post).

You also describe the restrictions ("the library is 3rd party code to which I dont have access"  "Is there any solutions which can be done without compiling the source again ?") which you neglected in your original post.   I suggest you edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Yes I agree. Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the source and compile with debug/no optimizations (i.e. 3rd party code.) the best you can do would be to disassemble the code and try to determine how the variables are stored.

In gdb the `disassemble` instruction will dump the assembly for the given function:

```
disassemble <function name>
```

Or if symbols have been stripped

```
disassemble <address>
```

where `<address>` is the entry point to the function.

You may also have to inspect where the function is called to determine the calling conventions used.

Once you've figured out the structure of the functions and variable layout (stack variables or registers), when debugging you can step through each instruction with `nexti` and `stepi` and watch how the values in the variables change by dumping the contents of the registers or memory locations.

I don't know any good primers or tutorials myself but [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/254963/416627) may be of use to you. Personally I find myself referencing the Intel manuals the most. They can be downloaded in pdf from Intel's website. I don't have a link handy at the moment. If someone else does perhaps they can update my answer.

Comment: Is there any documentation about reading the assembly code for x86_64 ? I know basics from my school knowledge about  MIPS, but have forgotten meaning of some instructions.

Comment: I don't have any resources I'm familiar enough with to recommend myself but I updated my answer with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at compiling your code un-optimized?

Try one of these in your `gcc` options:

```
-Og
    Optimize debugging experience. -Og enables optimizations that do not interfere with debugging. It should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience. 


-O0
    Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results. This is the default.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just updated my question, I dont want to do this :)

Comment: If the library is 3rd party code that you don't have access to, how are you doing ANY debugging at all?  You imply that you have symbols, and can view variables and source code; but this contradicts the statement that you don't have access to the library.

Comment: Ok, let me explain more, its like I have access to source code, but it takes ages to compile whenever I make change. So I thought instead of including too much details, I would just say this.